# wcf service not showing Publish option Why?

Tags: .net, wcf

I written one WCF service after that i am trying to Publish(after Build) this service. But solution not showing Publish Option and also not creating any .svc file in the solution why?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a WCF Service Library, or a Windows Service to which you then added a WCF Service class and scaffold?

If so, then this will explain it.

The Publish option only appears for web projects in VS - so that's either the Website or the Web Application Project.  Also, .svc files are only required for services that are hosted in Asp.Net as a file extension is needed (before any rewrite rules) to 'activate' the service host.

Create a new Website Application.

Add a new WCF service to it (which should also add the .svc), and then update the dummy interfaces & stub class with your service code.

Comment: I created WCF Service Library and How to create .Svc file is there any other way?

Comment: Thank u Andras Zoltan
my problem is cleared.But what is diff b/w wcf class library and web projects wcfservice?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434906/wcf-service-library-vs-class-library-project-types - also if my answer helped you then accept it so it can go off the board :)

Comment: How to accepct u  ra answer?let me know i wil do that

Comment: @Rajesh - apologies if I sounded terse.  This is your first SO question, so you're just getting to grips with it all.  Welcome and hope you'll be asking many more, as well as hopefully answering a few! :)